# Google cloud build failure: Service call error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Would like to ask if there is anyone who has encountered this problem with google cloud build:

```
Service call error. Function: [get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "users"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "9g5l9Jz2Sn299hI06e5I62zcVmeL"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "user_restaurants"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "restaurant_1"
  }
}
]. for 'create' @ L228
com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException: 
Service call error. Function: [get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "users"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "9g5l9Jz2Sn299hI06e5I62zcVmeL"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "user_restaurants"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "restaurant_1"
  }
}
]. for 'create' @ L228
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException$Builder.build(DatastoreException.java:111)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.verboseError(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.withVerboseErrors(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:266)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.checkCommit(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:118)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.commitHelper(CloudFirestoreV1.java:873)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.internalCommit(CloudFirestoreV1.java:780)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.internalCommit(CloudFirestoreV1.java:764)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.write(CloudFirestoreV1.java:753)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.handleRequest(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:208)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.write(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:136)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.onNext(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:92)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.onNext(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:25)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter$FirestoreWriteHandler.onMessage(FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.webchannel.FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter$FirestoreWriteHandler.onMessage(FirestoreV1WebChannelAdapter.java:111)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.onMessage(ChannelInternalImpl.java:485)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.deliverMessage(ForwardChannel.java:114)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.processPendingRequest(ForwardChannel.java:93)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.consume(ForwardChannel.java:67)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ForwardChannel.add(ForwardChannel.java:60)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.handleRequestParams(ChannelInternalImpl.java:260)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.processSessionRequest(ChannelInternalImpl.java:317)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.handle(ChannelInternalImpl.java:142)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.v8.ChannelInternalImpl.consume(ChannelInternalImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.net.webchannel.server.common.ChannelProcessor.run(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.common.EvaluationException: Error: /workspace/firestore.rules line [35], column [30]. Service call error. Function: [get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "users"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "9g5l9Jz2Sn299hI06e5I62zcVmeL"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "user_restaurants"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "restaurant_1"
  }
}
].
    at com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.impl.DefaultEvaluator$TransformEvaluationException.apply(DefaultEvaluator.java:292)
    at com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.impl.DefaultEvaluator$TransformEvaluationException.apply(DefaultEvaluator.java:277)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture$AsyncCatchingFuture.doFallback(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:204)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture$AsyncCatchingFuture.doFallback(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:191)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture.run(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:33)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1283)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:764)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.addListener(FluentFuture.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture.create(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:57)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.catchingAsync(Futures.java:411)
    at com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.impl.DefaultEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultEvaluator.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRuleClient$EmulatorRuleEvaluator.evaluate(EmulatorRuleClient.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRuleClient$EmulatorRuleEvaluator.evaluate(EmulatorRuleClient.java:81)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.core.auth.rules.SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer.evaluate(SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer.java:475)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.core.auth.rules.SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer.access$200(SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.core.auth.rules.SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer$CommitAuthorizerImpl.checkAccess(SinglePhaseRulesAuthorizer.java:702)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.lambda$checkCommit$0(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:126)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.withVerboseErrors(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:261)
    ... 21 more
```

I've recently updated our firebase sdk and firebase admin sdk to use the firebase emulator suite and at first our e2e tests are working perfectly, no flakiness at all. Then the only thing I did was merge the recent changes from our master branch to the branch I'm currently working on and it suddenly started failing inconsistently. I've checked the changes I have merged and nothing seems to be a probable reason for this issue. Hope someone can help point out to me why this error is happening.

Comment: perhaps it is related to this bug ? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5096 . Did you check the specific security rule at line 228 ? there is a get request to that path, it looks to me that the part that says (default) is incorrect. There should be no brackets at least and likely a full name. Did you try this in the real database, not emlator? may be an emulator bug only...

Comment: Yup, I've checked our security rules and its all okay. Also, this is something that only happens intermittently because most of the time the build passes. Also just an update, I think its an emulator bug since this isn't happening in our build anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it indicates there is a problem with the security rules at line L228. The issue is a get call with the mentioned segments.
Note that when a function call is made, it may still show the line where the call is made.

In this case it seems to me the (default) part is incorrect, since the name likely does not have braces, so it should be default or the segment name.

It might be an emulator bug or feature that shows this in an unclear matter ( see my comment referring to a bug I filed that might be related)

It could also be a timing issue, where you do a call to data that is not written yet, so regardless, I would check the database for the existence of:

```
/databases/(default)/documents/users/9g5l9Jz2Sn299hI06e5I62zcVmeL/user_restaurants/restaurant_1
```

perhaps this should be :

```
/databases/users/documents/users/9g5l9Jz2Sn299hI06e5I62zcVmeL/user_restaurants/restaurant_1
```